# How to enable split screen in my Android app?

Tags: android, multi-window, split-screen

I want to enable Split Screen for my android app. If I try to drag my app to make it occupy the top half of my android device it gives the message "App doesn't support split screen". However, for other apps such as Facebook and WhatsApp, I am able to use split screen. I am using LGE Nexus 5X with Android 7 (nougat) which supports split screen.

[image: Two apps running side-by-side in split-screen mode.]

Comment: Set your `targetSdkVersion` to 24 or higher.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add this to your `application` or `activity` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:resizeableActivity=true
```

Adding it to `application` will make all activities realizable, while adding it to a specific `activity` will keep other activities incompatible with resizing.

If your `targetSdkVersion` is 24 (Nougat) or higher, this will be set to true by default (you can still turn it off by setting the param to false).

Comment: will i have to use min sdk 24 for this ?

Comment: Nope :) It will simply have no effect in earlier system versions :-)

Comment: its not working for me :( . Target SDK is 27 in my case and android:resizeableActivity=true inside application tag.